# Werkzeug and class state with Flask: How are class member variables resetting when the class isn't being reinitialized?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, multiple-processes

I'm trying to write a flask extension that needs to persist some information between requests. This works fine when I run Werkzeug with a single process but when I run with multiple processes I get some odd behavior that I don't understand. Take this simple application as an example:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        print('initializing a Counter object')
        self.app = app
        self.value = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.value += 1
        print('Just incremented, current value is ', self.value)

counter = Counter(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    for i in range(4):
        counter.increment()
    return 'index'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #scenario 1 - single process
    #app.run()
    #scenario 2 - threaded
    #app.run(threaded=True)
    #scenario 3 - two processes
    app.run(processes=2)
```

For the first two scenarios it behaves exactly as I would expect: the Counter object is initialized once and then it increments with every request to the '/' route. When I run it with the third scenario (passing processes=2) then I get this as output:

```
 initializing a Counter object
  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 Just incremented, current value is  1
 Just incremented, current value is  2
 Just incremented, current value is  3
 Just incremented, current value is  4
 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2015 09:47:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 Just incremented, current value is  1
 Just incremented, current value is  2
 Just incremented, current value is  3
 Just incremented, current value is  4
 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2015 09:47:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 Just incremented, current value is  1
 Just incremented, current value is  2
 Just incremented, current value is  3
 Just incremented, current value is  4
 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2015 09:47:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

It seems that counter.value is returning to it's state right after being initialized without actually being re-initialized. Could somebody shed some light on what Werkzeug is doing internally to make this happen? I'd also be very interested in learning if there is a way to make this behave as I would naively expect (two processes, each with their own instance of Counter). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example (single thread) just uses the one `Counter`, so it works.

The second example (multiple threads), threads are spawned to handle each request.  They share the memory with the one `Counter` that was created before they spawn, so incrementing them from each increments the same thing.

The last example (multiple processes), processes are spawned to handle each request.  [Flask's dev server](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/0.10.4/werkzeug/serving.py#L484) uses [`fork`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.4.3/Lib/socketserver.py#l580): each child sees the same starting point (counter is already initialized) but increments in their [own address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) which goes away when the request ends.

```
import os

class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        print('init')
        self.value = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.value += 1
        print('inc -> {}'.format(self.value))

counter = Counter()

def multi():
    if not os.fork():
        # child starts with copy of parent memory
        for _ in range(3):
            # increments three times
            counter.increment()

        # child is done
        os._exit(0)

# three processes run
for _ in range(3):
    multi()
```

```
init
inc -> 1
inc -> 2
inc -> 3
inc -> 1
inc -> 2
inc -> 3
inc -> 1
inc -> 2
inc -> 3
```

---

Use a database or other external storage to store global state across processes, using `before_` and `after_request`.  Note that it's not exactly straightforward, since you'll have to make storing the incremented value of the counter from each request thread-safe, so that two threads don't overwrite the value at the same time.

```
req 1 starts, gets stored value = 4
req 2 starts, gets stored value = 4
req 1 increments, value = 8
req 1 saves, value = 8
req 2 increments, value = 8
req 2 saves, value = 8 but should = 12
```